# In C++, can you have a class member be a passed-in reference?

Tags: c++, reference

I have a 'StripManager' class that is responsible for updating the data of an already-existing 'Strip' class.  As such, the manager needs a reference to the strip.  Now I know I can pass in a pointer to the 'Strip' class to the constructor of the 'StripManager' class, but I'm wondering if there's any way to do that using references instead of pointers.  I just have always preferred dealing with references since you use them like the actual class instance rather than having to deal with pointer notation, etc.

So can this be done?

Here's some pseudo-code...

```
class StripManager
{
  public: 
    Strip &managedStrip;
    StripManager(Strip &stripToManage);
}

StripManager::StripManager(Strip &stripToManage)
{
    managedStrip = stripToManage;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize a reference, but not assign to it, so you need to use the member initializer list for this. It's good habit to use it instead of assignment in constructors anyway as it can be more efficient.

```
StripManager::StripManager(Strip &stripToManage) : managedStrip (stripToManage)
{
}
```

Note that having a reference member makes `StripManager` non-assignable (`StripManager a(strip1), b(strip2); a = b;` won't compile unless you write a custom assignment operator; even then, since you can't assign references, it's unclear what the semantics should be), which may or may not be a problem depending on your particular situation.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by my manager class is now non-assignable?

Comment: @MarqueIV As in, you can't write `StripManager a(strip1), b(strip2); a = b;`.

Comment: @MarqueIV A reference is not assignable, so it is hard to figure out what the semantics of assignment of a type with a reference data member would be. So it is ruled out by the standard. You can always implement the assignment operator, but, given what I said above, this would result in confusing code.

Answer (score 4):

A reference can only be ***initialized*** but not ***assigned***. So you cannot reassign the reference itself. You can do it in [member initialization list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) to initialize the reference member.

```
class StripManager
{
  public: 
    Strip &managedStrip;
    StripManager(Strip &stripToManage);
};

StripManager::StripManager(Strip &stripToManage): managedStrip(stripToManage)
{}
```